# Should a roof drip edge be placed above or below roofing felt?

Tags: roofing

I'm confused... I've seen two conflicting sources of information describing how a roof drip edge should be installed.

One source (Ask This Old House), states that a drip edge should be placed **above** roofing felt: https://youtu.be/dms-qDIUnUQ?t=11m31s

Another source (Handy Home), states that it depends on which side the drip edge it being placed... and the stuff on the sides should be **BELOW** the roofing felt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRciDPll_NY&feature=youtu.be&t=2m4s

Is this just a personal preference? Or is one method clearly superior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on where the drip edge is.  At the side, or gabels, of a roof, the drip edge goes over the roofing felt.  At the bottom of the roof, the drip edge goes under the roofing felt.  I have no idea why Ask This Old House did the drip edge the way they did.  The main purpose of underlayment is to keep water away from the decking if it gets under the shingles.  Water will pass right under that drip edge.

But don't take my word for it.  Your shingles will come with instructions that say how to place the drip edges.

#### Example Installation Instructions

[Timberline® Shingles Installation Instructions (PDF)](http://www.gaf.com/Residential_Roofing/Shingles/Timberline_Natural_Shadow/Timberline_Application_Instructions_English_Only.PDF)

> [image: Timberline® Shingles Installation Instructions]

[Oakridge® Shingles Installation Instructions (PDF)](http://www.owenscorning.com/NetworkShare/Roofing/10003280-Oakridge-Install-Instructions.pdf)

> [image: Oakridge® Shingles Installation Instructions]

<sup>Example installation instructions located using a simple google search. Products listed are not recommended nor endorsed by the author of this post.</sup>

Comment: Added some examples, hope you don't mind.

Comment: I think some places recommend placing the drip edge on top of the ice water shield even at the base in case water gets wicked up between the drip edge and the fascia. However, I agree, water coming down under the shingles would get under the drip edge. It's almost as if one would need a narrow layer of ice water shield under the drip edge, and then the "main" ice shield layer on top. Of course, I suppose one is also supposed to leave a gap between the drip edge and the fascia to avoid the wicking up as well...